# Lookup columns in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

After configuring 2 lookup columns in a library that uses 2 different lists for lookups, we are unable to view any new items added to the 2 lists in the lookup column in the library.  What would cause that?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried editing (but not changing anything) and saving the column settings?

Not every field you create in a list can be used in lookup columns, Name appears to be one of them, but you also won't see things like Multiple Lines of Text fields.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did not work.  If a user changes the Name field to Title, then uses that for the lookup item, will that cause an issue?